# Fab Button overlays BottomAppBar with HideOnScroll on Fling - Possibly a Bug

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

I'm using `FabButton` with `BottomAppBar`. The Layout Consists of a `RecyclerView` and the issue is when the user fling scrolls the `RecyclerView`, the `FabButton` overlays the `BottomAppBar` and takes 3-10 seconds to reset itself automatically. This behavior doesn't occur when the `RecyclerView` is scrolled a little bit or slowly. But, it looks like a buggy behavior to the user. Have a look at it and see, if there's a possible solution to this.

I'm using `HideOnScroll` property as `true` and changing the `FabAlignment` to `End` and `Center` when `BottomAppBar` hides or appears. It works okayish and this bug doesn't appear when I don't align the `FabButton` to the end when `BottomAppBar` is hidden but I want that.

You can watch the issue here : [Video - Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/050lq.jpg)

1. **XML Layout**

   ```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       android:id="@+id/coordinatorView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <include
           layout="@layout/sample_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

       <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
           android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"
           android:clickable="false"
           app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
           app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
           app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
           app:hideOnScroll="true"/>

       <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
           android:id="@+id/fabButton"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
           app:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
           app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"/>

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```
2. **Kotlin Code:**

   ```
   recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
       override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
           super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
           if (dy > 0) 
               bottomBar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END
           else if (dy < 0)
               bottomBar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER
       }
   })
   ```

And they have not provided the property `fabCradleVerticalOffset` to change it dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (dy > 0) 
            bottomBar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END
        else if (dy < 0)
            bottomBar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER
```

In this line of code you are doing that when the list is scrolled vertically so the fab icon will be moved to the end and if there is no scrolling then it will move to the centre so I think you should change this line of code or just work without it.

Comment: I just don't get how this can be an answer. Nope, not the solution I want.